Which way to use KL divergence in PyTorch is correct? And what if zero is in distribution?
I am trying to fit distribution p to distribution q with KL divergence.
import torch

p = torch.Tensor([0.1, 0.2, 0.7])
q = torch.Tensor([0.333, 0.334, 0.333])

So I calculate kl divergence by myself:
def kl_div(P, Q):
    return (P * (P / Q).log()).sum()

kl_div(p, q)

Result is tensor(0.2972)
Then I found that PyTorch has already implemented the torch.nn.functional.kl_div function.
I think input should be the network's output, and target is a constant.
So I treated p as the input and q as the target.
But result of
torch.nn.functional.kl_div(p.log(), q, reduction='sum')  # tensor(0.3245)

is different from mine.
And this one gets the same result as me.
torch.nn.functional.kl_div(q.log(), p, reduction='sum')   # tensor(0.2972)


So what went wrong?
Is there a problem with my understanding of kl divergence?
Or I filled in the wrong parameters of torch.nn.functional.kl_div?

And another question:
What if I have zero in the distribution?
Such as
p = torch.Tensor([0., 0.3, 0.7])
q = torch.Tensor([0.333, 0.334, 0.333])

I still need to calculate kl divergence in this situation.

KL divergence is undefined if any element of Q is zero and the corresponding element of P is nonzero.

but I need to calculate kl div when the distribution contains zero

You just flipped the distributions, generally p is considered the "target" and q the output. As for output distributions with 0, if you take log(0) = -inf, the KL-divergence is infinite. So if you "need" to have 0s in the distribution, you should look for another divergence.

KL Divergence is not symmetric. KL(P, Q) != KL(Q, P).
Pointwise KL Divergence is defined as y_{true} * log(y_{true}/y_{pred}).
Following this, your function:
def kl_div(P, Q):
    return (P * (P / Q).log()).sum()

Treats P as the true distribution. From your question, it sounds like you are treating P as the predicted distribution and Q as the true distribution, so you have things flipped relative to your function.
You may be confused because the mathematical notation KL(P||Q) defines P as a distribution of observations and Q as a "model" distribution, while the ML context uses P to denote the output of the model you are training and Q to denote ground truth observations from a dataset.
To your second question, KL Divergence is undefined when one of the values is zero. That is definitional to the metric. If P(i) = 0 and Q(i) > 0, this means P says event i is impossible while Q says it is possible - there is no measure on that discrepancy.
You can fudge it by adding a small eps to your values, ie torch.nn.functional.kl_div((p+1e-8).log(), q, reduction='sum'). However if 0 values come up often for your use case, you should consider a different metric.

aha, y_{true} * log(y_{true}/y_{pred}), I mixed up true and pred.
And in pytorch, it' salways F.kl_div(y_{pred}, y_{true}), so I actually get it right? the result is tensor(0.3245)?
